# BackgroundWorker for Multiple Operations

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to get get my BackgroundWorker to execute methods sequentially, one after the other, but I'm having no luck.

I feel it may be worthwhile to mention that I'm a SQL Developer by profession and I'm expanding my development scope.  I see no harm in that :)

I realize I can spawn new threads for the number of operations I have going but the operations I want to execute on the BackgroundWorker executes stored procedures in SQL Server, so running multiple queries on multiple threads all at once while hundreds of people are working on the server isn't ideal, since I store large volumes of data in my ETL tables.

So essentially what I have now is the following:

```
internal async void MethodA(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        // Execute Stored Procedure which populates an ETL Table
        // I use a SQLCommand object and call it using
        // await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }

internal async void MethodB(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        // Execute Stored Procedure which populates another ETL Table
        // I use a SQLCommand object and call it using
        // await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
```

I want to call these methods one after the other like this:

```
private void btnCreateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessMethodA();
        ProcessMethodB();
    }


void ProcessMethodA()
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            dtLossRatio.Clear();
            lblProgress.Visible = true;
            lblProgress.Text = "Building ETL A...";
            pbProcessWait.Visible = true;
            pbProcessWait.Location = new Point(420, 413);
            process = "ProcessA";
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }


void ProcessMethodB()
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            dtLossRatio.Clear();
            lblProgress.Visible = true;
            lblProgress.Text = "Building ETL B...";
            pbProcessWait.Visible = true;
            pbProcessWait.Location = new Point(456, 413);
            process = "ProcessB";
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

For my BackgroundWorker I have this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (process)
        {
            case "ProcessA":
                logic.MethodA(DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value);
                break;
            case "ProcessB":
                logic.MethodB(DateTimePicker3.Value, DateTimePicker4.Value);
                break;
        }
    }
```

I have a feeling these process changes should perhaps be altered in

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

I'm just not sure how to do this.

I've tried using a Task but I have no idea how to report the completion of one task for the code to start executing a new operation:

```
Task ExecuteProcessA()
    {
        Action invoker = new Action(ProcessA);
        return Task.Run(invoker);
    }
```

Any assistance would be great!

Comment: The equivalent of SSIS dataflows is ... TPL Dataflow. Background worker is an obsolete class that was only used for UI background processing of single operations. You can get equivalent functionality and *much* more just by using Tasks and async/await. TPL Dataflow on the other allows you to build pipelines of steps, even allow a single step to process multiple messages/rows in parallel. Not something you can do with SSIS. I'm using TPL Dataflow for ETL to process and import complex input files and then process the rows with SSIS

Comment: As for asynchronously awaiting the completion of a Task, just use `await Task.Run.(..)` or `await thatTaskReturnedFromA`; `await` doesn't block, it releases the current(UI)  thread until the task completes, then resumes on the original thread on completion.

Comment: Get rid of the IsBusy tests, those just hide bugs in your code.  It is never useful to try to sequence the code on the UI thread, your DoWork event handler can trivially do it.  Use ReportProgress to show progress.  And maybe get ahead with the more modern Task class and async/await, it is more compatible with the way you think about this.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not a seasoned C# developer ^_^.
I don't know exactly how to use a Task because if I try `await Task.Run(ProcessA())` the compiler gives me an error saying a Task cannot execute a void.  An example would be ideal to point me in the right direction...

Comment: That's the wrong syntax. You are telling `Task.Run` to execute the *result* of `ProcessA()`. You need to pass an Action or lamba, eg `Task.Run(()=>ProcessA())`. That would be OK for *control flow* though. For actual dataflow, I'd create a Dataflow where each block would process a single row, transform it and pass it to the next. This way, each step would run on its own thread. Then I'd change the MaxDOP setting of some steps to process multiple rows in parallel. Not all steps are suitable for this though.

Comment: To send the results to the database, I'd create a BatchBlock to batch, eg 1K rows together and pass it to an ActionBlock that would use SqlBulkCopy to send the rows to SQL Server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I sort of get what you're trying to say regarding lambda expressions & I'll give it a bash.  However, I'm not posting data to the database from my application.  The stored procedures handle the population of my ETLs.  I just pass parameters to my stored procedures via the C#.  The C# code only triggers these stored procedures.  
What I'm trying to do is wait for one stored procedure to finish executing before the next one starts...without calling a stored procedure from within a stored procedure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I feel it may be worthwhile to mention that I'm a SQL Developer by profession and I'm expanding my development scope.

I recommend that you read my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [`async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) articles. I also have a whole series on [why you should replace `BackgroundWorker` with `Task.Run`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html).

> running multiple queries on multiple threads all at once while hundreds of people are working on the server isn't ideal

Definitely true, and something a lot of .NET devs don't think of. :)

> So essentially what I have now is the following:

One of the primary lessons from my [article on `async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) is "avoid `async void`". `async void` is unnatural; the proper return type for an `async` method without a return value is `Task`, not `void`. You do *have* to use `async void` in certain situations (most notably asynchronous event handlers), but you should use `Task` unless you *have* to use `void`.

So, if we just change those methods to return `Task` instead:

```
internal async Task MethodAAsync(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
internal async Task MethodBAsync(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
```

Then...

> I want to call these methods one after the other

is actually pretty easy:

```
await MethodAAsync(startDate, endDate);
await MethodBAsync(startDate, endDate);
```

In fact, I don't think you need `Task.Run` (or `BackgroundWorker`) at all:

```
private async void btnCreateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
  dtLossRatio.Clear();
  lblProgress.Visible = true;
  lblProgress.Text = "Building ETL A...";
  pbProcessWait.Visible = true;
  pbProcessWait.Location = new Point(420, 413);
  await logic.MethodAAsync(DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value);

  Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
  dtLossRatio.Clear();
  lblProgress.Visible = true;
  lblProgress.Text = "Building ETL B...";
  pbProcessWait.Visible = true;
  pbProcessWait.Location = new Point(456, 413);
  await logic.MethodBAsync(DateTimePicker3.Value, DateTimePicker4.Value);
}
```

Comment: This actually makes a whole lot of sense.  I'd give you a Bell's, Sir!

I'll add your recommendations to my solution and let you know what the outcome is when I get to it.  As mentioned, my SQL dev takes priority over C# but it's definitely a skill worth having I think :)

Comment: Yeah, this is 100% what I'm looking for.
Thanks SO much dude.  Much appreciated!! :)